# Getting rid of @Autowired (removing Spring dependency)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I was recently given a Java project to work on that contains a bit of Spring, and I was asked to get rid of it. I don't know anything about Spring and would rather not spend a day learning about it.

Most of the dependency I can see is with @Autowired. Do you have any advice for how to remove @Autowired? Is it as simple as making a singleton and setting the @Autowired fields manually?

Comment: Is the plan to use a different Dependency Injection container, or to cook up something yourself?

Comment: TBH Dependency injection is overkill in this project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring detects the @Autowired fields and sets the field to one of the "beans" that exists and can be configured with Spring.

Even though the beans are mostly singletons, I believe it is possible for Spring to use non-singleton autowirings as well.

Since you have not provided any code (which I can understand why), I suggest you look at the fields that are autowired and determine if they are used as singletons or not. If they are, then yes it can be as simple as making a singleton and setting the fields manually.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the standard Java `javax.inject.Inject` dependency injection annotation? Spring also supports that one for resolving dependencies, if that class is on the classpath. In most situations you could simply replace the Spring `@Autowired` with `@Inject`. See the [Javadoc of `@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) and the [Spring reference on `@Inject` support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inject-named).

Answer (score 0):

If you use constructor dependency injection, then it is ok to remove @autowired annotation. System will determine it as default